Metric space property of balls
Is it true that for a complete metric space $X$, for every continuous function $\epsilon:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, there exists a continuous function $\delta:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that for any $x'\in X$ if $x\in B_{\epsilon(x')}(x')$  then $B_{\delta(x)}(x)\subseteq B_{\epsilon(x')}(x')$?
Ideas:As $B_{\epsilon(x')}(x')$ is open, for any $x\in X$, there exists $\delta_x>0$ such that $B_{\delta_x}(x)\subseteq B_{\epsilon(x')}(x')$. But $\delta:B_{\epsilon(x')}(x')\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ given by $\delta(x)=\delta_x$ is only defined locally and don't have to be continuous. If $\delta$ is continuous, then maybe partitions of unity will give what we want?

Let $\varepsilon:(0, \infty)\to (0, \infty)$ be $\varepsilon(t) = t$. Then the open balls $B(t, \varepsilon(t))$ are sets $(0, a)$ for some $a > 0$. But if $x\in (0, \infty)$ and $s > 0$, then $x\in (0, x+s/2)$ but the ball around $x$ with radius $s$ isn't contained in $(0, x+s/2)$.

What I'm saying that you can't find such $\delta$ at all. Continuous or not.

@Jakobian Sorry. I added $X$ is complete

Your idea is wrong/incomplete by the way. You need $B_{\delta_x}(x)$ to be contained in $\bigcap_{x'} B_{\varepsilon(x')}(x')$ where the intersection goes over all $x'$ such that $x\in B_{\varepsilon(x')}(x')$. So you need $x$ to belong to interior of it.

@Jakobian $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is open ball.

If you want $X$ to be complete then take $X = [1, \infty)$ and $\varepsilon:X\to (0, \infty)$ as above. Then open balls $B(t, \varepsilon(t))$ are sets $[1, a)$ for $a \geq 2$. Take $x = 2$ for example, and any $s > 0$. Then $x\in [1, x+s/2)$ but the ball around $x$ with radius $s$ isn't contained in $[1, x+s/2)$.

So even if $X$ is complete, then can be no such $\delta$ at all.

@Jakobian I see. Thank you. This is helpful and elightening. Is this property ever true? (e.g. Hilbert spaces maybe?)

If you take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon(t) = \max(1, t)$ in my example, you obtain an example where no such $\delta$, continuous or not, can exist. So no, not even for Hilbert spaces.

Your comments should really be an answer @Jakobian

Here $B(x, r) = \{y\in X : d(x, y) < r\}$. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean metric and $\varepsilon:X\to (0, \infty)$ be defined as $\varepsilon(t) = \max(1, t)$.
Suppose that there exists a function, not necessarily continuous, $\delta:X\to (0, \infty)$ such that $B(t', \delta(t'))\subseteq B(t, \varepsilon(t))$ for any $t'\in B(t, \varepsilon(t))$ and $t\in X$.
Let $s = \delta(2)$. Then $2\in B(1+\frac{s}{4}, \varepsilon(1+\frac{s}{4})) = (0, 2+\frac{s}{2})$ but $B(2, s) = (2-s, 2+s)$ is not contained in $(0, 2+\frac{s}{2})$ since $2+\frac{s}{2}\in (2-s, 2+s)$ but $2+\frac{s}{2}\notin (0, 2+\frac{s}{2})$.
So such function $\delta$ cannot exist, continuous or not.
